# inject UTC time into the page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using several literals to inject the user's time onto the the page. The values in the HTML are the UTC times.

```
var TheDay = parseInt($('#UserDayToday').html(), 10);
var TheMonth = parseInt($('#UserMonthToday').html(), 10);
var TheYear = parseInt($('#UserYearToday').html(), 10);
var TheHours = parseInt($('#UserTimeStampHours').html(), 10);
var TheMinutes = parseInt($('#UserTimeStampMinutes').html(), 10);
```

Now I want to build a time stamp with that time so I tried this:

```
var TheDateToday = new Date();
TheDateToday.setUTCFullYear(TheYear, TheMonth, TheDay);
TheDateToday.setUTCHours(TheHours, TheMinutes, 0, 0);
alert(TheDateToday);
```

When the alert comes on, it gives me the time with his timezone shift added. How can I just have the the UTC time. I know I can get it from the browser but I want to get the UTC time built from the data sent from the server, not retrieved from the user's machine by the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are displaying the date in local time. Use the [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) method instead of the implicit [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) method:

```
alert(TheDateToday.toUTCString());
```

Comment: When I do this, it shows GMT as the timezone; is this the same thing?

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, for general purposes they mean the same thing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time